# How can i create a loop that checks a users input to see if it is an existing file?

Tags: c++

I need the user to enter a file and for as long as the user enters files that exist the file will loop. The program will break when the user enters a file that does not exist.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string currentfile;
    int i = 0;
    do {
        cout << "Please enter a file name \n";
        cin >> currentfile;
        cout << currentfile << "\n";
        ifstream myfile(currentfile);
        if (myfile.good())
        {
            // display thenumber of characters, words, and lines in that file
            myfile.close();
        }
        else {
            cout << "break";
            break;
        }
        i++;
    } while(true);
    // repeat while user enters valid file name
}
```

when i enter a file that exists, `myfile.good()` returns good then if i try a file that does not exist the like `myfile.good()` returns true again. If i start the program and i try first a file that does not exist `then myfile.good()` returns false.

I do not know why after i enter a valid file `myfile.good()` will continue to return true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to check is this :

```
ifstream myfile(currentfile);
if (myfile) // myfile.is_open() is fine too...
{
    // display thenumber of characters, words, and lines in that file
    myfile.close();

}
else {
    cout << "break";
    break;
}
```

good() :

> checks whether the stream is ready for input/output
>   operations, other member functions exist to check for specific states
>   of a stream (all of them return a bool value)

It checks state flags.

To test if a file was successfully opened, you would use :

```
myfile.is_open()
```

And then, if it was, you would perform checks like : eof(), ..., or good().

Example :

```
ifstream myfile(currentfile);
if (myfile.is_open())
{
    while ( myfile.good() ) // while ( !myfile.eof() ), ...
    {
        getline (myfile,line);
        cout << line << endl;
    }
    myfile.close();
}
```

[This](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/) for more details.

Comment: This is mainly what my question is about and the problem i cant figure out.

Comment: Chances are, if you started with a valid file then changed to an invalid file, the stream is still ready for I/O. Which I would consider a bug, but hey, C++.

Comment: Yep, it's exactly that. `good()` only returns false when any of the following return true: `bad()`, `fail()`, and `eof()`. `fail()` is a superset of `bad()`, and returns true if a r/w operation fails or a format error happens - which will happen with an invalid file, but apparently the flag does not get re-set. Use `clear()` to reset the flags.